# ExtJS 4 desktop taskbar - how to get height programmatically

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

It would be helpful to get the taskbar's height programmatically when sizing windows and preventing them from covering the taskbar. I can hardcode the height in window size calculations for now, but would appreciate a better approach.

Comment: What taskbar?  I don't see any reference to "taskbar" in the ext4 documentation or source code.

Comment: Take a closer look at Ext.ux.desktop.App and do a search for getTaskbarConfig().

Comment: please add your comment as an answer and accept it tomorrow.

Comment: @James Clark: the desktop app is a demo app from Sencha: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/desktop/desktop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not needing the taskbar height value anymore, because there is a way to get the desktop height without the taskbar:

```
_myDesktopApp.desktop.body.dom.clientHeight
```

Before, I was using:

```
_myDesktopApp.desktop.getHeight()
```

Which gave me the combined height.

So to get the taskbar, if I ever need it, I can do:

```
_myDesktopApp.desktop.getHeight() - _myDesktopApp.desktop.body.dom.clientHeight
```